# After bundling my aurelia app I get a: No PLATFORM.Loader error

Tags: aurelia, jspm

After bundling a simple aurelia application with `jspm bundle-sfx` I get the following error:

`No PLATFORM.Loader is defined and there is neither a System API (ES6) or a Require API (AMD) globally available to load your app.`

An example application: https://github.com/Baudin999/jspm-bundling-test

You can use: `npm run setup:dev` in a non windows env to switch back to the dev settings (which is just a comment/uncomment in the ./src/client/index.html) and you can use `npm run setup:prod` to switch back to the production environment, bundling will automatically be triggered. all other scripts can be found in the `package.json`.

I can't link to other questions because I haven't found any questions which relate to this problem. I "think" (which means absolutely nothing) that this might be related to the fact that aurelia needs a full loader even when bundling with `bundle-sfx` but I haven't found any ways to solve the error.

---

EDIT (25/01/2017 17:16): I've found out that the error is because I import the `aurelia-bootstrapper`.
As soon as I add: `import * as bootstrapper from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';` I get the error

---

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code how do you bootstrap your aurelia app.
There is nothing actually to import from bootstrapper apart from bootstrap function.
Which you would use in case of custom manual bootstrapping.

like in

```
import { bootstrap } from 'aurelia-bootstrapper'
const configure: (au: Aurelia) => {} = async function (au: Aurelia) {


    au.use
        .standardConfiguration();

    await au.start()
    au.setRoot() // or au.enchance()
})

bootstrap(configure)
```

in a happy path scenario with jspm - you System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper') 
and it takes over finding the root node of your app and the script to configure Aurelia (main by default)

Have a look at [Bootstrapping Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/app-configuration-and-startup) in the docs

Oh.. and `bundle-sfx` is not supported there are other means to bundle aurelia apps using jspm

Comment: Thank you for answering. I had an example application with the bootstrapping etc. This question is very old and if I could I would "close" it. I myself have moved to React. I don't even have the example anymore

Comment: Well seing that there are at least 4 upvotes to your question I assumed there are others with the same question. So it was worth answering

Comment: You are completely right, but I don't have my old bootstrap code anymore. If I had it I would have posted it. I know this makes this issue irrelevant and I would love to close it.