# Aurelia and Webpack 3

Tags: aurelia, webpack-3

I just upgraded from Webpack 2.x to the latest 3.0, and my Aurelia app breaks at load time with the following message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) No PLATFORM.Loader is defined and there is
neither a System API (ES6) or a Require API (AMD) globally available
to load your app.
```

Is there a known issue with Webpack 3 and Aurelia? I saw this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815624/after-bundling-my-aurelia-app-i-get-a-no-platform-loader-error) question but learned nothing from it.

Comment: **Update:** I upgraded _html-webpack-plugin_ to 2.29.0 - the latest version at the time of writing this comment - and all is back to normal.

Comment: Similar for me, but updates to **html-webpack-plugin to 2.29.0** not helped

Comment: Ever resolve this?